# ipywidgets: Update one widget based on results from another

Tags: python, widget, ipython, ipywidgets

I am using widgets in IPython that allows the user to repeatedly search for a phrase and see the results (different titles) in another widget (a selection widget) and then select one of the results.

In short:

```
search_text = widgets.Text(description = 'Search') 
search_result = widgets.Select(description = 'Select table')

def search_action(sender):
    phrase = search_text.value
    df = search(phrase) # A function that returns the results in a pandas df
    titles = df['title'].tolist()
    search_result.options = titles

search_text.on_submit(search_action)
```

This used to work fine, but after updating to the latest version of ipywidgets (5.1.3 from 4.0.1) it seems like

```
search_selection.options = titles
```

Produce the following errors (one or both, it varies):

```
TraitError: Invalid selection
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

It still works in the sense that the widget gets updated with the results based on the search from the other widget, but it gives an error.

What is the correct way of setting the options in one widget based on the results from another widget?

(edit: added more detailed error message)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hold notifications for during the assignment to `options`:

```
with search_result.hold_trait_notifications():
    search_result.options = titles
```

Thus:

```
search_text = widgets.Text(description = 'Search') 
search_result = widgets.Select(description = 'Select table')

def search_action(sender):
    phrase = search_text.value
    df = search(phrase) # A function that returns the results in a pandas df
    titles = df['title'].tolist()
    with search_result.hold_trait_notifications():
        search_result.options = titles
```

See hmelberg's explanation below

> "The root of the error is that the widget also has a value property and the value may not be in the new list of options. Because of this, widget value may be "orphaned" for a short time and an error is produced."

Comment: Could you extend this so that your solution works with copy + paste? :)

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this exact problem an hour ago. I have hacked together a solution using the minimum example here: [Dynamically changing dropdowns in IPython notebook widgets and Spyre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529157/dynamically-changing-dropdowns-in-ipython-notebook-widgets-and-spyre), since my own requirements were to have dynamically linked lists. I am sure you'll be able to adapt your requirements using this solution.

The key is to pre-generate all Dropdowns/Select. For some reason, `w.options = l` only sets `w._options_labels` but not `w.options`. Subsequent validation of the selected value of `w` will then fail horribly.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

geo={'USA':['CHI','NYC'],'Russia':['MOW','LED']}
geoWs = {key: widgets.Select(options=geo[key]) for key in geo}

def get_current_state():
    return {'country': i.children[0].value,
            'city': i.children[1].value}

def print_city(**func_kwargs):
    print('func_kwargs', func_kwargs)
    print('i.kwargs', i.kwargs)
    print('get_current_state', get_current_state())

def select_country(country):
    new_i = widgets.interactive(print_city, country=countryW, city=geoWs[country['new']])
    i.children = new_i.children

countryW = widgets.Select(options=list(geo.keys()))
init = countryW.value
cityW = geoWs[init]

countryW.observe(select_country, 'value')

i = widgets.interactive(print_city, country=countryW, city=cityW)

display(i)
```

Note lastly that it is not trivial to obtain the most up-to-date state of the widgets. These are

- directly from the children's values, via `get_current_state`. This can be trusted.
- from the interactive instance, via `i.kwargs`
- from the supplied args to `print_city`

The latter two can sometimes be out of date, for various reasons I don't wish to find out further.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it [Registering callbacks to trait changes in the kernel](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html#Registering-callbacks-to-trait-changes-in-the-kernel)

```
caption = widgets.Label(value='The values of range1 and range2 are synchronized')
slider = widgets.IntSlider(min=-5, max=5, value=1, description='Slider')

def handle_slider_change(change):
    caption.value = 'The slider value is ' + (
        'negative' if change.new < 0 else 'nonnegative'
    )

slider.observe(handle_slider_change, names='value')

display(caption, slider)
```

I guess this solution wasn't available back in 2016 or my problem wasn't as similar as thought.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the error is that the widget also has a value property and the value may not be in the new list of options. Because of this, widget value may be "orphaned" for a short time and an error is produced.

The solution is either to assign the widget value to the option list before assigning it to the widget (and remove the value/option after if desired), or as Dan writes: use create a hold_trait-notifications()

Dan's approach is the best. The above just explains the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, and the .hold_trait_notifications() context manager mentioned by Dan did not solve it.  Instead I implemented a debounce decorator on the function that was causing the issue.  Instructions can be found on the Jupyter Widgets documentation for [Debouncing](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html).  Implementing it involves adding this code block before your code:

```
import asyncio

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, timeout, callback):
        self._timeout = timeout
        self._callback = callback

    async def _job(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(self._timeout)
        self._callback()

    def start(self):
        self._task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._job())

    def cancel(self):
        self._task.cancel()

def debounce(wait):
    """ Decorator that will postpone a function's
        execution until after `wait` seconds
        have elapsed since the last time it was invoked. """
    def decorator(fn):
        timer = None
        def debounced(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal timer
            def call_it():
                fn(*args, **kwargs)
            if timer is not None:
                timer.cancel()
            timer = Timer(wait, call_it)
            timer.start()
        return debounced
    return decorator
```

Then your function should be modified with the @debounce decorator added like so:

```
@debounce(0.2)
def search_action(sender):
    .....
```

I hope this works for you too :)