# Multiple dependent widgets (dropdown menu) on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, drop-down-menu, widget, jupyter-notebook

I was following the example on how to handle multiple dependent widgets on jupyter notebooks from here:

[Dynamically changing dropdowns in IPython notebook widgets and Spyre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529157/dynamically-changing-dropdowns-in-ipython-notebook-widgets-and-spyre/29333253)

In that example the code solution was the following:

```
from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import display

geo={'USA':['CHI','NYC'],'Russia':['MOW','LED']}

def print_city(city):
    print city

def select_city(country):
    cityW.options = geo[country]


scW = widgets.Dropdown(options=geo.keys())
init = scW.value
cityW = widgets.Dropdown(options=geo[init])
j = widgets.interactive(print_city, city=cityW)
i = widgets.interactive(select_city, country=scW)
display(i)
display(j)
```

so, the second dropdown is dependent on the value of the first one.
Here the question: **What if i want to create a third dropdown that is dependent on the value of the second one?** Let's say that each of the cities above (CHI, NYC, MOW, LED) have some districts, and I'd like a third dropdown that change every time that a city is updated.

Hope that the problem is clear, thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258847/using-multiple-depended-widgets-from-jupyter-notebook-and-interactive-problem

Comment: hey can you check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258847/using-multiple-depended-widgets-from-jupyter-notebook-and-interactive-problem I could need some help

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you never found a solution: I have one here that works in python 3. I've commented everything that I changed from the original code. I hope it helps!

```
from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import display

geo={'USA':['CHI','NYC'],'Russia':['MOW','LED']}

geo2={'CHI':['1','2'],'NYC':['3','4'],'MOW':['5','6'],'LED':['7','8']} #create dictionary with city districts

def print_city(city,district):
    print(city)
    print(district) #add in command to print district

def select_city(country):
    cityW.options = geo[country]

#add in 'select district' function that looks in the new dictionary
def select_district(city):
    districtW.options = geo2[city]

scW = widgets.Dropdown(options=geo.keys())
init = scW.value
cityW = widgets.Dropdown(options=geo[init])


init2= cityW.value #new start value for district dropdown
districtW = widgets.Dropdown(options=geo2[init2]) #define district dropdown widget

j = widgets.interactive(print_city, city=cityW, district=districtW) #define district value
i = widgets.interactive(select_city, country=scW)

k = widgets.interactive(select_district, city=cityW) #call everything together with new interactive

display(i)
display(j)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `interactive` is somewhat clumsy for me. I have provided an answer clearer and conciser for two dependent widgets in the original page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529157/dynamically-changing-dropdowns-in-ipython-notebook-widgets-and-spyre/59029874#59029874). Below I provide my answer for multiple dependent widgets.

```
from ipywidgets import interact, Dropdown

geo = {'USA':['CHI','NYC'],'Russia':['MOW','LED']}
geo2={'CHI':['1','2'],'NYC':['3','4'],'MOW':['5','6'],'LED':['7','8']}

countryW = Dropdown(options = geo.keys())
cityW = Dropdown(options = geo[countryW.value]) # options = geo[countryW.value] is to remove inital error but not that necessary.
districtW = Dropdown()

@interact(country = countryW, city = cityW, district = districtW)
def print_city(country, city, district):
    cityW.options = geo[country] # Here is the trick, i.e. update cityW.options based on country, namely countryW.value.
    districtW.options = geo2[city] # Dittoo
    print(country, city, district)
```

An alternative would be to use explicit update functions shown as follows. Bear in mind that the update speed may not be that quick. The code works well.

```
from ipywidgets import interact, Dropdown

geo = {'USA':['CHI','NYC'],'Russia':['MOW','LED']}
geo2={'CHI':['1','2'],'NYC':['3','4'],'MOW':['5','6'],'LED':['7','8']}

countryW = Dropdown(options = geo.keys())
cityW = Dropdown()
districtW = Dropdown()

def update_cityW_options(*args): # *args represent zero (case here) or more arguments.
    cityW.options = geo[countryW.value]
cityW.observe(update_cityW_options) # Here is the trick, i.e. update cityW.options based on countryW.value.

def update_districtW_options(*args):
    districtW.options = geo2[cityW.value]
districtW.observe(update_districtW_options)

@interact(country = countryW, city = cityW, district = districtW)
def print_city(country, city, district):
    print(country, city, district)
```

Comment: great answer. Working well. However, sometimes I see that the axis gets duplicated 2 times. The first plot is the plot we want, the second and the third are plots where the axes are replicated. Any idea on how to ignore them?

Comment: @prashanth thanks for your comment. Yes you are right that we will get 1/2 duplicated items if we change 2/1 level values. Sorry I do not have a solution to this for the time being. Once I get it resolved I will reply here.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.