# How to tell `ipywidgets.interactive`, that it should consider only specific parameters as widgets?

Tags: python-3.x, widget, default-value, interactive, ipywidgets

It seems like `ipywidgets.interactive` tries to make every imput after the function to be a widget. In the following example, I get two widgets, one for `age` and one for `name`:

```
import ipywidgets 

def greetings(age, name='John'):
    print(f'{name} is {age} years old')

ipywidgets.interactive(greetings, age = widgets.IntSlider(), name = "Bob")
```

My expectation was, that I only get one widget for `age`, since it is of type `ipywidgets.widgets.widget_int.IntSlider` whereas `"Bob"` is of type `str` (where I don't see the link to widgets). The automated widget creation causes two problems: 1. I don't want that the user can specify every parameter 2. Some parameters like tuples (not shown in the example) will result in an error.

**How to tell `ipywidgets.interactive`, that it should consider only specific parameters as widgets?**

`help(ipywidgets.interactive)` and [the documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html) were not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for the clear example and description.

You can leverage the `fixed` function in ipywidgets to pass fixed kwargs of any type through your interactive call, but without generating widgets for them. See below:

```py
import ipywidgets 

def greetings(age, name='John'):
    print(f'{name} is {age} years old')

ipywidgets.interactive(greetings, 
                       age = ipywidgets.IntSlider(), 
                       name = ipywidgets.fixed("Bob")
                      )
```

You should also be able to pass tuples through this method. See more information in the documentation: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Fixing-arguments-using-fixed